# How to allow a user to create databases only with specified prefixes in DolphinDB?

Tags: acl, sql-grant, dolphindb

Since databases are created for various business requirements, to better manage users in my group, I want to enable access control on databases they created. Specifically, I hope that users are only allowed to create databases with specified prefixes.

For example, allow users to create only the databases with specified prefixes, e.g. "factor". Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the version 2.00.9, DolphinDB allows users to create databases with a specified prefix. For example:

```
createUser(`user1,`123456)
grant(`user1, DB_OWNER, "dfs://factor*")
```

The user1 is granted only the privilege to create the database whose name begins with "dfs://factor".

There is another point to note: if another user has created such a database, user1 cannot access it without the DB_OWNER privilege. To access it, additional privilege is needed.